# linux-Ruby - run a ruby application as a command

Tags: ruby, linux

I want to run a lib of ruby files from the command prompt from anywhere in a command line. I have the Main.rb program which instantiates classes from other ruby files.

I store the class path of my lib in the .zshrc. Then I run the Main.rb but it is not able to load the required ruby files (files in my lib folder) and throws this error:

```
`require': no such file to load -- Data.rb (LoadError)
```

How can I tackle this issue? I just need a neat command to be run on shell and throw results on console.

Please help.

Comment: Try putting this at the top of `Main.rb`: `$: << '.' unless $:.include? '.'`

Answer (score 2):

Ruby searches the directories in the $LOAD_PATH variable to try to find files you import with the 'require' statement. You have a few options:

1. move your files to a directory in the $LOAD_PATH list
2. give Ruby the path to your libraries in your require statement:

   require '/home/mydir/myproject/lib/Data.rb'
3. modify $LOAD_PATH in Main.rb to include your lib directory
4. pass Ruby a command-line argument adding your lib directory to $LOAD_PATH with the -I option:

   ruby -I/home/mydir/myproject/lib Main.rb

Comment: Hey $: << '.' unless $:.include? '.' doesnot work plus how can I just use it as a normal command say test or just Main without any .rb thing...

I m planning to use the third option above but still dono how to include this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll need to change your

```
 require 'abc'
```

to a relative path, like

```
 require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/abc"
```

or use (my) require_relative on 1.9

```
 require_relative 'abc'
```

GL.
-r